# Can't query hits.product row in Bigquery Google Analytics Export

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Currently running into issues querying data from the hits.product row in BQ as it seems to be behaving differently to the other hit level data in the GA export. Here is my query below. Works fine if looking at hits.page but not so for the hits.product fields.

```
 SELECT
  case when hits.product.productbrand = "Gucci" then "gucci" else " " end
  FROM
  `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_20170822`,
  unnest(hits) hits
```

The error I get is "Error: Cannot access field productBrand on a value with type ARRAY> at [2:26]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hits.product` is also an ARRAY field, so you also need to unnest it. Maybe this works for you:

```
 SELECT
   CASE WHEN prods.productbrand = "Gucci" THEN "gucci" ELSE " " END brand
 FROM
    `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_20170822`,
 UNNEST(hits) hits,
 UNNEST(hits.product) prods
```

Comment: Thanks Will, absolute pro.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this will flatten all outer rows which will cause their fields to be duplicated. If you are not using other outer fields nor any other computation then this query should already be enough :)